# Laggy keyboard input on elementary OS compared to Windows 10

Tags: keyboard, laptop, input, microsoft-windows

On my computer keyboard input has a 1> second delay compared to Windows 10 which has 0 delay.

The computer is a Sony Vaio VGN-NR120E and it has always been like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that the Slow Keys option has somehow gotten turned on? You can find this option in the "Universal Access" section of settings.

[image: Slow Keys in settings]

Comment: I will try this

Comment: Thank you very much !!(!) I was beginning to think I had to learn to program.